# Slidetoggle is not working correctly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two containers, one shows grouped boxes, quantities and totals, and the other container shows details.

The div data value of each container is created on run time dynamically. both containers have the data, but the default container to show on page is the grouping one.

Those values are grabbed using jQuery to display in what is a "preview" table, outside of the div containers.

I am trying to use slidetoggle to switch the containers at the click of a link and that part works. The problem I am having is with the table, all the values are incorrect when they display the first time, and subsequently as the link is clicked

Here is a link that shows my jQuery script so far: [My jsfiddle][1]

The test mark-up:

```
<div class="ToogleGroupContainer">                        
<div class="shipToSingleSection">
        <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
                <div class="shoppingCart_Box">Box#01</div>
                <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">5</div>
                </div>
        <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each 26.99</div>
        <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price 134.95</div>                
            </div>
            <hr />           
</div>  
<div class="shipToMultipleSection" style="display:none;">
           <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
                <div class="shoppingCart_Box">Box#01</div>
                <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">1</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">1</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">1</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">1</div>
                    <div class="shoppingCart_qty-select">1</div>
                </div>
        <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each 26.99</div>
        <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price 26.99</div>

            </div>
            <hr />
</div>
</div>
<table class="tableOrderPreviewTotals" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td class="yord_hdr">Item</td>
        <td class="yord_hdr_center">QTY</td>
        <td class="yord_hdr_center">Each</td>
       <td class="yord_hdr_center">Price</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="yord_line_item" stlye="display:none;">
            <div id="itemOrderPreview"></div></td>
        <td class="yord_line_qty" stlye="display:none;">
            <div id="qtyOrderPreview"></div></td>
        <td class="yord_line_right" stlye="display:none;">
            <div id="priceEachOrderPreview"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="yord_line_right" stlye="display:none;">
            <div id="subtotalEachOrderPreview"></div>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<a href="" class="shipToMultipleLink">Ship Order to Multiple Addresses</a>
```

You will see how messy it is right now. I need to be able to show the values correctly, depending of which container is shown on the page.

The default display should be:

Item    QTY      Each    Price

Box#1   5       26.99   134.95

When the Ship to multiple addresses link is clicked (toggle), the table line should be:

Item    QTY      Each    Price

Box#1   1       26.99    26.99

Box#1   1       26.99    26.99

Box#1   1       26.99    26.99

Box#1   1       26.99    26.99

Box#1   1       26.99    26.99

When the Ship to sinlge addresses link is clicked (toggle), the table line should be (like default):

Item    QTY      Each    Price

Box#1   5       26.99   134.95

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.shipToMultipleLink').click(function () {
            $('.shipToMultipleSection, .shipToSingleSection').slideToggle('fast');
            return false;

        });

            $.each($('.shipToMultipleSection .shoppingCart_qty-select'), function () {
                $("#itemOrderPreview").append($(".shoppingCart_Box").html()).append("<br>")
                $("#qtyOrderPreview").append($(this).html()).append("<br>");

                var each = $('.shoppingCart_Price_Each').html().replace(/Each/,"")
                $("#priceEachOrderPreview").append(each).append("<br>");

                var price = +each * $(this).text()
                 $("#subtotalEachOrderPreview").append(price).append("<br>");
            });

      var h = '<tr class="singleLine" style="display:none;">'
      /* edited */
      h += '<td>' + $(".shoppingCart_Box").html() + '</td>'
      h += '<td>' + $(".shoppingCart_qty-select").html() + '</td>'
      h += '<td>' + $('.shoppingCart_Price_Each').html().replace(/Each/,"") + '</td>'
      h += '<td>' + $('.shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each').html().replace(/Price/,"") + '</td>' 
      h += '</tr>'
      $(".tableOrderPreviewTotals tr:last-child").after(h)

    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/k3t0cbcc/4/
is this what you require?

Comment: It is closer, I updated the original comment with sample of how it should work/ look. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, it is ok. The line totals are backwards, and the default to be displayed should be the grouped totals. Is it hard to show single line for grouped data, multiple lines for details, and show grouped line as default? Many thanks sir.

Comment: What you did is great, is just that is backwards, not at the div level, but at the table level.

Comment: fantastico! molto grazie Alessandro!

Comment: Dont forget rate the answer ;-)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I just ran into an issue with your solution. When there are multiple single items like box 1, box 2, box 3, the single line row only captures the values for box 1.

Comment: the grouped lines show correct, but the detail lines do not show the correct quantities for box #2. thank you

Comment: yes, http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/k3t0cbcc/13/ but is an example.. i think that the html code is generated for you..js only read and group what read inner html tag

Comment: I am getting an error when I plug your code in: TypeError: $(...).children(...).html(...) is undefined
h += '<td>' + $(this).children('.shoppingCart_Price_Each').html().replace(/Each/...
it points to this part: $(this)

Comment: I think I got it, my real html structure is a bit different that the one used in the fiddle.

Comment: Alessandro. I got it to work for the single but for the multiple, only for the shoppingCart_Box class. The html is different on the real page and it does not recognize the class for the Each column. This is how my html looks: <div class="shoppingCartPrice"><div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $26.99</div><div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $26.99</div></div>

Comment: It works for the single line using children, but for the multiple line display, the each and price are not working. The description and quantity does work.

Comment: I tried without luck, this: h += '<td>' + $('.shoppingCartPrice').parent().next('.shoppingCart_Price_Each').html().replace(/Each/, "") + '</td>'
- Same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66794/discussion-between-alessandro-marchisio-and-itortu).

Answer (score 1):

Dude, that's really messy..

Just for a start, check your jQuery, for example:

```
 $('shipToMultipleLink').hide();
 $('shipToSingleLink').show();
```

Should be

```
 $('.shipToMultipleLink').hide();
 $('.shipToSingleLink').show();
```

Then please, tidy it up a little bit, and explain better your problem so we can help you out..

Comment: Hi Joaquín O, I updated the fiddle, but I am far from done. I have not figured out how to display by default the values from grouping container, and then correctly after each toggle. Thank you for pointing out the syntax errors.

Comment: Haven't seen your update yet.. Is it something like this what you need?  http://jsfiddle.net/7k4reyn1/

Comment: Your example is nice, but I don't understand how the toggling that you do on the table row will work for the data I have.

Comment: The table is supposed to use the data from the div tags. In your example, I don't understand how to put the data in the respective div(s), have the table empty, and fill it with the data from the div(s). Having the default be the grouped data. I hope this makes sense, I am probably not understanding your solution.

Comment: Hi Joaquín, I tried your fiddle and added a second box, when I add the second box with different values, the values are retrieved, but displayed incorrectly, would you take a look at it? I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7k4reyn1/4/

Comment: Here it is updated.. Hope it's usefull.. Anyway, this is not good programming.. I don't know why you had to do this, but it's not good for developer's eyes... Mark the answer if it solved your problem, please.. http://jsfiddle.net/7k4reyn1/5/